# Как проверить наличие cocoapods в проекте?

Tags: cocoa, xcode, ios

Вопрос в заголовке. Самое банальное - проверить наличие файла *.podspec. Будет ли это правильным?

Answer (score 1):

Ну для чистоты можно проверить файл: project.pbxproj находящийся в [iosProject].xcodeproj. На наличие подобных строк:

```
F816C65EBAD24D80BF9BAEFF /* libPods.a in Frameworks */ = {isa = PBXBuildFile; fileRef = B4B49B48343143B3B1E2AFFA /* libPods.a */; };
A78719A9B62344A383C4D417 /* Pods.xcconfig */ = {isa = PBXFileReference; includeInIndex = 1; lastKnownFileType = text.xcconfig; name = Pods.xcconfig; path = Pods/Pods.xcconfig; sourceTree = "<group>"; };
F816C65EBAD24D80BF9BAEFF /* libPods.a in Frameworks */,
```

ну и так далее...

Comment: У CocoaPods есть такая опция как `--no-integrate`, с ней CP просто выкачивает зависимости, но в проект их не добавляет, (это можно использовать для ручного подключения сторонних библиотек в виде фрэймворков) в таком случае ваша проверка будет иметь ложные результаты.

Comment: Но ведь тогда проект не будет зависит от cocopods? Так как он не будет даже знать о его существовании. И где искать хедеры? И проект можно будет запустить как самостоятельный без `.xcworkspace`? Если это так, то следовательно, проект не зависит от cocopods.

Comment: Речь о наличии, а не о зависимости ;)

`Podfile`  в любом случае будет присутствовать.

Comment: Лаааадно @AlexDenisov, ты как всегда опять убедил :) Хотя область видимости Проекта спорная :р

Answer (score 0):

Вам автоматически или глазами?

Все проекты с CocoaPods имеют Podfile со списком зависимостей, смотрите в его сторону.